# How do I stop online searching by maven connectors?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

How do I stop the online searching by maven m2e connectors for the dependencies when I have already overridden the functionality for them to have local library instead of central by pom file by giving url like :

```
<repository>
    <id>central</id>
    <url>file://${basedir}/library</url>
</repository>
```

My all other files get downloaded(I mean copied) from the library which exists at local except some which I have not included in the library. Is there any way that connector too only search for the local library. My log is  something like below.

```
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 5.413 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-09-18T15:22:36-05:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 12M/125M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------
------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project myproject: Could not resolve 
dependencies for project com.company.product:myproject:jar:1.0: Failed to 
collect dependencies at org.glassfish.jersey.media:jersey-media-json-
jackson:jar:2.19 -> com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs:jackson-jaxrs-
base:jar:2.5.1 -> com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.5.1: 
Failed to read artifact descriptor for 
com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.5.1: Could not transfer 
artifact com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:pom:2.5.1 from/to 
release.maven.java.net (https://maven.java.net/content/groups/public): 
sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: 
sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to 
find valid certification path to requested target -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
```

Here I am running package as a goal. I can provide more details if you ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quite simple, ask your central repository to get redirected to local repository in your settings.xml file. Example given below. Let me know if further help required.

```
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0
                      http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
  ...
  <mirrors>
    <mirror>
      <id>central-repo</id>
      <name>Local repo</name>
      <url>http://<localhost>/central</url>
      <mirrorOf>central</mirrorOf>
    </mirror>
  </mirrors>
  ...
</settings>
```

Comment: No I can't as my .m2 file is deleted everytime when I build my project and it is rebuild again

Comment: No worries, these changes are supposed to be outside .m2 directory. Edit your settings.xml inside Maven_Dir/conf/settings.xml

Comment: I have partial installation and i think I have installed it as a plugin so where can I find the global settings.xml

Comment: No worries, you can rebuild it and use it as plugin

Comment: Set `settings.xml` location in Eclipse: _Window > Preferences: Maven > User Settings_

Answer (score 0):

You can try -o option (offline).
Example command line:
    mvn clean package -o

Comment: It can not help if you need to be online without downloading dependencies but with constant updates.